# Get interface name of a SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh

I'm creating a layer 3 SSH tunnel with this command:

```
ssh  -w any:any root@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I want to know the name of the interfaces that it creates. Typically it's tun0, but it varies.

I could force use a specific name, but that could cause a conflict with an existing name. There should be a way to retrieve that name.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-v` to your ssh invocation, then capturing the output and grepping for the tunnel device name.  Unfortunately I'm not able to say any more than that, since I can't get that feature to work at all on my server.